# top menu's position fixed but on scroll part from next div disappears

Tags: javascript, html, css

The div class="first" is a top menu that I wanna try to make it fix on scroll
so I used this code, everything is working fine but the problem is that when I start scrolling half of the next image mid-top.jpeg
in the next div class="second" disappear.

it is like image mid-top.jpeg comes under the image top.jpeg

How can I fix this?
thanks!

```js
var fixmeTop = $('.first').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
        $('.first').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
        });
    } else {
        $('.first').css({
            position: 'static'
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
    <img src="images/top.jpeg" alt="">
    <map name="">
        <area target="" alt="" title="home" href="index.html"  coords="1,60,95,115" shape="rect">
    </map>
</div>
    
 <div class="second">  
    <img src="images/mid-top.jpeg" alt=""> <!--problem here-->
    <map name="">
        <area shape="" coords="" href="" alt="">
    </map>
</div>
```

Comment: This is happening because `.first` is positioned on top of `.second` and so when you scroll down it covers it up. What would you like to happen?

Comment: when I scroll back to the top again the .second is permanently covered by .first 
so when I scroll up again I want to be able to see .second again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with CSS only.

Set `.first` to `position: fixed`

Vertically offset `.second` by the height of `.first` using `margin-top`

```css
.first {
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.second {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  <map name="">
    <area target="" alt="" title="home" href="index.html" coords="1,60,95,115" shape="rect">
  </map>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  <map name="">
    <area shape="" coords="" href="" alt="">
  </map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is img top.jpeg suppose to be part of the fixed menu? If not, it should be moved out of the .first div. That could explain why your second image is moving under the first.